# VCRUNTIME140_1.dll missing after building solution with c++

Tags: c++, dll

[image: h c++]

I've created a small text adventure. I've built the solution with Visual Studio Community 2019 using Release and x64 settings. I've zipped up the *.exe file along with the other generated files and sent them to another pc that doesn't have VS installed and the error you see in the image came up. I've searched my pc and the file exists in a couple of different folders, one of them being system32 so i don't know where to place the file on the new pc.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You'll need to install the [Visual Studio 2015 runtime redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=48145) on the target PC. I don't recommend moving the DLLs from your PC to the target or downloading the DLLs individually off the Internet as both leave avenues for the unscrupulous to do evil things to the target PC.

Comment: Ok. Will do. Thank you so much for the answer :)

Comment: That is not the VS2015 runtime.  Deploying the version you tested your program with is best.  Just copy the file into the same directory as your EXE, the 32-bit version is in c:\windows\syswow64, the 64-bit version in c:\windows\system32.

Comment: @HansPassant I have just encountered this issue for the very first time with a Italian user. He is getting the same error x64 in Italian. I don't quite understand why you say "That is not the Vs2015 runtime". I have never had to include other DLL files before like this.

Answer (score 24):

Per @user4581301's comment, the answer is to download a current Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable for the appropriate architecture (i.e. x64).

As I already had a 2019 of the redestributable installed, I had to install the corresponding [2015-2019 x64 distributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

Comment: It doesn`t help in my case. Downloaded the most fresh vc_redist.x64.exe and 
VC_redist.x86.exe (there are 2015-2019 versions packed in). After reinstallation there is no VCRUNTIME140_1.dll nor in system32, nor in SysWOW64. Have to check for viruses by several antiviruses, it is clean. Got 32-bit version of VCRUNTIME140_1.dll from whatsapp desktop app and put it to system32, it helped to many apps installed. Now have no idea, where to get 64-bit version. Win10pro 64.

Comment: Solution by @aleksander-wisniewski worked for me finally, it really brings missing file. And it looks like there is no 64-bit version of that library.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the most voted solution and was still missing it. Found out that MS actually has a different version of VC redist inside [Visual Studio download page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/). Look inside the Other Tools section. After installing that, one missing DLL was added.

Comment: The download called 'Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019' worked for me. When installing it is called 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) - 14.27.29112', which is a bit weird. It is certainly different to the VS 2015 redistributable. The C++ tools versions and VS versions are not longer in sync.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helps, other solutions didn`t work (Win10Pro 64)!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and installed `VCRUNTIME140_1.dll` file and put it in the MySQL Shell 8.0 bin file.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install both the x86 and x64 versions of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 - 2019 Redistributable [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0)

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing this issue. The below solution worked for me.
Solution:

1. Download the VCRUNTIME140_1.dll file
2. Place it in the path - C:\Windows\System32

Check if it solves your problem.

Comment: But where did you download it from?